# JSONException being thrown in Android app

Tags: java, android, json, rest

I have an iOS app and an Android app that work with a RESTFul webservice.

When I make my query to the service, I get a JSON object returned like so.

```
[
    {
        "id": 21,
        "device_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "api_key": "yyyyyyyyyy",
        "customer_id": 28,
        "created_at": "2014-12-08T11:21:01.517Z",
        "updated_at": "2014-12-13T04:40:44.295Z",
        "registered_at": "2014-12-08T11:22:49.960Z",
        "install_date": "2014-11-18",
        "serial_number": "1121113",
        "last_communication_at": "2014-12-13T04:40:44.283Z",
        "avg": null,
        "min": null,
        "max": null,
        "usage_updated_at": null,
        "usage_period_days": null,
        "settings_change_upload_interval": 5,
        "stats_upload_interval": 1440
    }
]
```

iOS has no problem retrieving and parsing the JSON information.

On Android I'm trying to use JSONObject to serialize the response I get (BTW, I'm getting a valid status code of 200 from the URL Request)

```
JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

But this is throwing an exception saying that the JSONObject is not of the proper format.

I have other calls to the API that are working ok, so it's something about this particular JSONObject that is causing the problem.  Is it because a couple of those values are returning as null because they aren't set in the database yet?

Like I said, the iOS JSON serialization of this packet is working just fine.

Comment: its a JSONArray, as far as I can see..

Comment: `[]` stands for array (even if it has only one element), `{}` is object. Use `JSONArray`.

Comment: that's not a json object -> close as typo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to parse an array to object, that's why its giving exception. Also, don't forget to put a `try-catch` block around it.

Use this

```
try
{
    JSONArray myArr = new JSONArray(result);
    JSONObject myObj = myArr.getJSONObject(0);
    int id = myObj.getInt("id");
}
catch (JSONException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give that a shot.  I do have the catch in there.

Comment: Try it, it would do the job!  :)

Comment: As soon as I get back home tonight I will give it a shot.  Thank you so much.